# instantiate multiple instances of objects and sent to jsp

Tags: java, oop, jsp, servlets

How should I do this?

I have a form that could send 1-5 values of the same parameter: so for an example I could have the user fill out 3 text boxes each containing their favorite color. I would grab those values from using:

```
String [] color = request.getParameterValues("color");
```

which would give me an array of those values. Then my plan was to do something like this:

```
for(int i= 0; i<color.length; i++)
    {
        Child child = new Child(color[i]);
        request.setAttribute("color",color);

    }
```

Firstly would this create three separate attributes named "color" or would this override the "color" attribute each time?

Secondly how would I collect that information out on the final page?

```
<% Color color =(Color) request.getAttribute("color"); %>
```

Would this return only one value or an array of the objects I created?

Answer (score 0):

> Firstly would this create three separate attributes named "color" or
>   would this override the "color" attribute each time?

The setAttribute will override the attribute "color" and you will have available just the last variable. But you can do:

```
Child [] childs = new Child [color.length];
for(int i= 0; i<color.length; i++)    {
    Child child = new Child(color[i]);
    childs[i] = child;
}
request.setAttribute("colors",childs);
```

So in the JSP you can retreive the colors as following:

```
<% Child[] childs =(Child[]) request.getAttribute("colors"); %>
```

Comment: thanks but how would I access the object properties once I have the attributed requested in the jsp?

Comment: you can use a loop for and access through childs[i].getSomeAttr(), if the length of your vector is fixed, you can access directly throug the index childs[2].getSomeAttr()